# moving a SVG circle element with jquery

Tags: jquery, svg

I have the following HTML code

```
<svg>
<circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

I then ran the following Javascript code from browser console:

```
jQuery('circle').attr('cy');
```

This gave the output:

```
SVGAnimatedLength {animVal: SVGLength, baseVal: SVGLength}
```

But for the output, i was expecting the string `50%`.  Why did it not give me the string `50%`? Likewise, if i do a

```
jQuery('circle').attr('cy', '55%');
```

I expected the circle to move 5% down.  But nothing happened.

How do I use jQuery to move this circle?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you're using jQuery 1.5 or earlier. Am I correct?

Comment: you're right, my project is using jquery 1.4.4  So i guess i have to upgrade?

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

Comment: Well, it's a good idea to for many reasons, and yes, it will be much easier if you upgrade to a modern version. The functioning of `attr` in this kind of situation was a question addressed in jQuery 1.6, which was released two and a half years ago.

Comment: lonesomeday - can yo post your answer so i can accept?